# C code for interpreting Java HelloWorld byte code

Tags: jvm, interpreter, bytecode

What is a simple C/C++ code which can interpret a java class file (byte code) which only contains `System.out.print()` statements.(I had a look at simple opensource JVMs but they are bit complex because of the completeness.) 
Or where can I find a well explained guide to make an interpreter (i.e explanation of Java byte code)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to do this?  This is pretty involved and there is very likely a much better approach.

Comment: Q: Are you looking for a decompiler (just to understand the byte code) or an interpreter (to actually run it)?  [DJ Decompiler](http://download.cnet.com/DJ-Java-Decompiler/3000-2213_4-10046809.html) is arguably one of the best; it only costs $20.00 USD.  IMHO...

Comment: You might also want to look at [JSava](http://blog.zortrium.net/archives/96)

Comment: @paulsm4 I need an interpreter(simplest possible)

Comment: @templatetypedef I'm trying to make a jvm for a different platform(microkernel baesed).Therefore I need to understand how it works.I guess this is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for the [*Java Virtual Machine Specification*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html).

While your question may seem trivial at first, this is only because of how well a facade the JVM places over the internal aspects of even a simple class like this:

```
final class WorldGreeter {

    public static void main(final String[] argv) {
        System.out.println("Greetings, Earth!");
    }
}
```

Reading through the fifth chapter of the specification, namely [*Loading, Linking, and Initializing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html), you'll see there is plenty of work a virtual machine must do to run even the most simple programs.

To point out the necessity of all of these complex stages, I'll be assuming you're using the standard Oracle JDK; according to [this blog post](http://luckytoilet.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/how-system-out-println-really-works/), you'll expect the initialization of System.out to require quite a bit of work -- namely, the loading of several various classes, and more importantly a working JNI layer.

Now, there's no reason you'd need to be using the Oracle JDK implementation... sure, you could use a more simple setup, but most of the structure and work put into the loading, linking, and initialization stages still stands. It's not as easy as your hunch might tell you.